# Anyway to tell in msal.js if authentication was an existing user login or a new user signup

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-react

We are using `@azure/msal-browser` and `@azure/msal-react` and have the standard authentication flow in our React app, as is show in the code samples below.

We are using Azure External Identities user flow where the users can either login or, if they don't have an account, they are given an opportunity to sign up for one and are then taken to the app.

Is there anyway to detect in the app if a successful authentication was a result of a login or of a new user sign up?

I see that there are several event types defined in the source code here (and I can catch many of them in the console while the user is signing in); however, none of them correspond to the event of a new user sign up:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/60c4aafa5/lib/msal-browser/src/event/EventType.ts

**Config**

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}`,
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_TENANT_ID}`,
    redirectUri:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? 'http://localhost:3000/'
        : process.env.REACT_APP_DEPLOY_URL,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            console.error(message);
        }
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**Main app component**

```
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

<MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
  {!isAuthenticated && <UnauthenticatedHomePage />}
  {isAuthenticated && <Protected />}
</MsalProvider>
```

**Unauthenticated component**

```
const signInClickHandler = (instance: IPublicClientApplication) => {
  instance.loginRedirect(loginRequest).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
};

<UnauthenticatedTemplate>
  <Button onClick={() => signInClickHandler(instance)}>Sign in</Button>
</UnauthenticatedTemplate>
```

**Protected component**

```
<MsalAuthenticationTemplate
  interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect}
  errorComponent={ErrorComponent}
  loadingComponent={LoadingComponent}
>
    ... the rest of the app ...
</MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG I spent a lot of time for this. Then I found your post and... no answers :D (more sad)

BUT... I found this :O
[image]

And works! ;)

Comment: You are using Azure B2C, I am using Azure External Identities B2B and it doesn't look like that option is there for me unfortunately. For my situation, I managed to find a work around which isn't ideal, but I will post an answer below anyway.

Comment: I see.... Yea I was thinking to use similar workaround before I found that claim which can be returned.
**I wish there an event type more specific than just EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS to my situation.**

I agree with this :)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I am using at the moment is below: essentially anytime a user logins, I check if I have a record of this user in a dedicated table in the database. If there isn't a record, it must be a new user and I add the record to the database. So, next time when the user logins in, there will be a record and this user must be an existing user.

This approach makes unnecessary calls to the database for returning users; however, they are quite simple and quick calls - not ideal, but ok for my situation.

I wish there an event type more specific than just `EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS` to my situation.

```
const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    
instance.addEventCallback((message: { eventType: any }) => {
  if (accounts.length > 0 && message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
          
  // Make an API call to the database to see if there is any history about
  // this user, if not, then it must be a new user.
  }
});
```